# Blender quit showing the words when I open it

Tags: installation

I have Blender on my Acer Aspire One laptop and I have only been using it for almost 2 weeks and when I open blender it won't show what anything is labeled no matter what I click. No words. Just pictures. Can you please help me with this and tell me how to fix it??

Comment: Quite likely it's your graphics drivers OpenGL.  Make sure they are up to date.  Can you post the specs, graphics card , driver versions. Minimum Requirements http://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: Show a screenshot that will help us to see where you are. Could it be that it opens into the image editor? Does pressing Escape do anything?